# Error while opening port in Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I am getting the following error while trying to open the cash drawer.

`Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_15\jre\bin\win32com.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`

The code i am using is as follows

```
import javax.comm.*;  
import java.util.*;    
/** Check each port to see if it is open. **/  
public class openPort {  

  public static void main (String [] args) {  
      Enumeration port_list = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers ();

      while (port_list.hasMoreElements ()) {
          // Get the list of ports
          CommPortIdentifier port_id =
                  (CommPortIdentifier) port_list.nextElement ();

          // Find each ports type and name
          if (port_id.getPortType () == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
          {
              System.out.println ("Serial port: " + port_id.getName ());
          }
          else if (port_id.getPortType () == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)
          {
              System.out.println ("Parallel port: " + port_id.getName ());
          } else
              System.out.println ("Other port: " + port_id.getName ());

          // Attempt to open it
          try {
              CommPort port = port_id.open ("PortListOpen",20);
              System.out.println ("  Opened successfully");
              port.close ();
          }
          catch  (PortInUseException pe)
          {
              System.out.println ("  Open failed");
              String owner_name = port_id.getCurrentOwner ();
              if (owner_name == null)
                  System.out.println ("  Port Owned by unidentified app");
              else
                  // The owner name not returned correctly unless it is
                  // a Java program.
                  System.out.println ("  " + owner_name);
          }
     }
  } //main
} // PortListOpen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated previously, the [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) you are using (2.0, not current 3.0 that is not implementation available for Windows) is for Windows 32bit, so the win32com.dll must be used with a 32bit JRE/JDK, not a 64bit JRE/JDK. Try using the JDK 1.6.0_15 32 bit version.

Answer (score 3):

The error clearly saying that your dll is 32 bit. JVM should be 32 bit also.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you use a 32bit JDK on a 64bit platform. Try a 64bit JDK! Or if available, install the 64bit version of the API.

Comment: i have NetBeans workin on this version of JDK. Will there be any kind of issues if i change it to 64 bit now ? i should remove java and should reinstall am i rite ?. And if i install 64 bit JDK the application i am developing on this will work on all platforms or not ?

Comment: You app will run without problems on all platforms and JDKs, given that the right comm api is installed. Typically, I would recommend to stay on 32bit Java, because its faster also on 64bit windows versions, but it seems that the Comm API uses native DLLs, so on 64bit Windows, a 64bit JDK and Comm API seems to be required, and on 32bit windows the 32bit Comm API. Just try it. For the IDE it plays no role, you can also use a 32bit JVM for the IDE and a 64bit JDK to run your programs from the IDE.

Comment: i prefer not to chagne the version of my JVM.. is there any other way to fix this ?